# Sending SMS in automated batches AND through web-interface

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, batch-file

This is more about the design/efficiency of the application rather than the syntax - I need to create a process that sends a batch of texts that will be run on a scheduler (automated batches), but I also need to allow an admin to send a batch manually (manual batch) or individual SMS messages (triggered). My initial thought was to build a server-side console application that can be executed with parameters to handle the sending of all texts, but I'm not positive if this would be the best option. I'm a bit worried about conflicts arising with multiple instances of the console app running (which I would obviously need to code for). Any suggestions on the best way to tackle this?

The batches will process one at a time in a loop, which will post the message to the operator (Twilio) and log the message in our database as sent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It probably depends on your operator. [This one has quite a lot of tech samples and docs](http://www.clickatell.com/developers/clickatell_api.php).

Comment: I can recommend Clickatell having used them myself recently their documentation is very clear and helpful

Comment: @Purplegoldfish : Good to know, thanks ! I had their site in my bookmarks "just in case" and because I found their documentation interesting.

Comment: Thanks. We've decided to use Twilio as our operator (though I really love the documentation and feature set of the one you linked to). From the research I've done, it appears that Twilio just wants clients to send a post request for each message to be sent, so my batches will simply be a loop to post each message individually.